# Need to change program filtering of files getting from FTP

Tags: c#, .net

I've a C# program that received FTP records. The files we receive are all .csv so I check for that below:

```
private static bool IsAllowedExtension(string fileExtension)
        {
            return  fileExtension.ToLower() == ".csv";
        }
```

then we process only this sort of file:

```
 foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
                                {
                                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileInfo.Name);
                                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension) || !IsAllowedExtension(fileExtension))
                                        continue;

                                    if (!Directory.Exists(LocalPath))
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalPath);

                                    var localFile = string.Format("{0}\\{1}",LocalPath.TrimEnd('\\') , fileInfo.Name);

                                    if (fileInfo.Name != ".." && !File.Exists(localFile))
```

However, now there has been some .csv in the group receiving we dont want. So i want to add or change this to that the file we want all start as this:

"CheckoutReportID=" this would give us only the ones needed.

Comment: do you want to filter files by name or by content ?

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension) || !IsAllowedExtension(fileExtension) || !fileInfo.Name.StartsWith("CheckoutReportID="))
                                    continue;
```